# How to change active class when link is selected?

Tags: php, jquery, html-lists

I have the following menu

```
<div class="gw-sidebar">
  <div id="gw-sidebar" class="gw-sidebar">
    <div class="nano-content">
      <ul class="gw-nav gw-nav-list">
         <li class="arrow-down"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="gw-menu-text"> <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>PROJECT</span> <b class="gw-arrow"></b> </a>
          <ul class="gw-submenu" id="main" style="display: none;">
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "project" ? "active" : "")?>" id="pro"> <a href="<?php echo PRODUCTS . 'project' ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>ADD PROJECT</a> </li>

          </ul>
```

I got $page which is project but class is not active. Then I tried jquery

```
$('.gw-nav > li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('active');
            $('.gw-nav > li > ul > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active')
        });
```

also not working.I tried a lot.
But below code is working perfect

```
 <li class="arrow-down"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span class="gw-menu-text">Category 3</span> <b></b> </a>
          <ul class="gw-submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 1</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Which is working well.But if i add href link for php page its not working.

I don't know what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `ul` have `style="display: none;"` so you aren't able to see that `li` at-all. So how you come to know that `active` class is not added ?Did you checked through browser debugger?

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have css styles

Comment: if something is hide, then css style on it will not shown too.

Comment: Avoid `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` in favor of `$(this).closest("selector")`